# How to Use Left join in multiple Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need all my records from T3 Table in below query.
how can I use left join statement to solve my problem in oracle.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)

  FROM  R
  LEFT JOIN  RD
    ON (R.ID = RD.RES_INFO_ID)
  LEFT JOIN  RES
    ON (R.SEL_EVL_RES_ID = RES.ID)
  LEFT JOIN  S
    ON (S.ID = R.SEL_EVL_ID)
  LEFT JOIN  D
    ON (RD.DEC_DET_ID = D.ID)
  LEFT JOIN  M
    ON (S.EVL_MAS_ID = M.ID)
  LEFT JOIN  P_RES
    ON (P_RES.PRS_ID = RES.PRS_ID)
  LEFT JOIN  P_MAS 
    ON (P_MAS.PRS_ID = M.PRS_ID)
  LEFT JOIN  P_EVL
    ON (P_EVL.PRS_ID = S.PRS_ID)
  LEFT JOIN  P
    ON (P.EVL_MAS_ID = M.ID)
  LEFT JOIN  DM
    ON (DM.EVL_RES_INF_DET_ID = RD.ID);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why do you think that a left join is the way to go?

Comment: By using this query I achieve bulk of persons that they are evaluate and have score. and these scores are assign in T4 table. and persons that they haven't any score or any evaluate them (raw persons)are store in T3 table. Now I want In addition to prev query , the new requirements will also be considered (bulk of persons that haven't  any score). because of that I think the left join is worked. but I don't know. maybe Union statement is better soution!

Answer (score 0):

If you need all records from `T3`, then that should be the first table in the `FROM` clause.  All the joins should be `LEFT JOIN`s.  I presume you intend:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T3 R LEFT JOIN
     T1 S
     ON S.ID = R.SELF_EVALUATION_ID LEFT JOIN
     T2 RD
     ON RD.EVL_RESOURCE_INFO_ID = R.ID LEFT JOIN
     T4 RES
     ON R.SELF_EVALUATION_RESOURCE_IDRES.ID LEFT JOIN
     T5 M
     ON S.EVALUATION_MASTER_ID = M.ID LEFT JOIN
     T6 D
     ON RD.DECENCY_DETAIL_ID = D.ID LEFT JOIN
     T7 P
     ON P.EVALUATION_MASTER_ID = M.ID LEFT JOIN
     T8 DM
     ON DM.EVL_RES_INFO_DETAIL_ID = RD.ID;
```

In the future, follow a simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax with the join conditions in the `ON` clause.